# Should I retract my duplicate flag if the question is improved in comments?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Here is the case:

1. I have marked a question with the duplicate flag.
2. Someone answered the question with an answer which gave yet another error which was mentioned in the comments section.
3. The question is still not updated but from the comments section, it’s evident that the duplicate flag no longer applies.

Should I retract the flag?

Comment: ... how would the duplicate no longer apply? are you saying the answer in the duplicate is incorrect? else the new error may warrant a new question with its mcve

Comment: @SurajRao no, the original answer(for which this one is a duplicate of) was correct, but required further refinement in this case. Now the error is the one he described in the comments, so my duplicate flag doest not apply here

Comment: If the clarification exists only in the comments, the flag still applies. Edit that question with that information from the comments, and then it might not apply.

Comment: should the OP be asked to edit or just edit myself ?

Comment: Either. You can ask the OP to edit it. You can edit it yourself (but write a very detailed edit message, since it would need to be approved in review).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This sounds like the original question is a duplicate of a question you identified, and after solving it the OP found another problem and is now asking (in comments so far) a new, unrelated question.

If that is the case, they should post the new problem as a separate question; the dupe flag holds.

Comment: this is exactly the case, so should the OP be notified to post it as a separate question?

Comment: Yes, they should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 9):

- **Don't change close votes based on what's written in the comments** (unless the comment merely shows that you misunderstood or misjudged something).
- **If the asker gives more information regarding their question in a comment**, that should be edited into the question<sup>[1]</sup> (by either you<sup>[2]</sup> or the asker), at which point you can change your close vote if what's now written in the question justifies it.
- **If the asker asks about a different issue in the comments** than what they asked in their question (which sounds like the case here) (even if both of these issues are with the same code posted in their question<sup>[3]</sup>), that should be asked in a separate question.

  This is especially true if the question already has one or more answers.

[1]: ... unless the question is already closed and this edit wouldn't address the close reason(s). Editing brings attention to the post, and may also add it to the reopen queue if it's a closed question, which we don't really want to do if the question is closed and should remain closed.

[2]: If you don't have full edit privileges (i.e. you have less than 2k reputation), make sure to add an edit summary explaining that you're adding a comment from the asker into the question, and also fix any other issues with the post.

[3]: ... in which case they probably didn't post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which could be reason enough to close the question.